# combine BranchPythonOperator and PythonVirtualenvOperator

Tags: airflow

I have a `PythonVirtualenvOperator` which reads some data from a database - if there is no new data, then the DAG should end there, otherwise it should call additional tasks e.g

```py
#dag.py

load_data >>[if_data,if_no_data]>>another_task>>last_task
```

I understand that it can be done using `PythonBranchOperator` but I can't see how I can combine the venv **and** the branch-operator.

Is it doable?

Comment: The PythonVirtualenvOperator is the load_data ? have you considered returning true/false with xcom ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using Xcom.
`load_date` can push the number of records it processed (new data).

Your pipe can be:

```
def choose(**context):
    value = context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='load_data')
    if int(value)>0:
        return 'if_data'
    return 'if_no_data'

branch = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='branch_task',
    provide_context=True, # Remove this line if Airflow>=2.0.0
    python_callable=choose)

load_data >> branch >>[if_data,if_no_data]>>another_task>>last_task
```

Comment: What if I want to stop when `if_no_data` is triggered i.e `another_task` and `last_task` should only be run after `if_data`

Comment: Nvm, I figured out adding `another_task.set_upstream(if_data)` and `last_task.set_upstream(another_task)` before `load_data >> branch >>[if_data, no_data]` made the deal

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by using `BranchPythonVirtualenvOperator`

```
    branching_venv = BranchPythonVirtualenvOperator(
        task_id="branching_venv",
        requirements=["numpy~=1.24.4"],
        python_callable=branch_with_venv
    )
```